# PHP - multiple function return TCPDF variables

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have lot of code for creating pdf (TCPDF) separate by header, body, footer...
and I need to call the code as needed with variable coordinates. Because I need use `if else` calls are (of course) multiple and needlessly I rewrite the same code.

For example I try this (subheader):

```
class invoice {
   function getSubheader($disY){
      $subheader = array(
         $pdf->SetLineWidth(.2),
         $pdf->MultiCell(190,9,'',1,'L',false,0,10,$disY,true),
         $pdf->SetFont('freesans','',7),
         $pdf->MultiCell(50,"",$getDesc['blabla1'],0,'L',false,0,12,$disY+2,true),
         $pdf->MultiCell(15,"",$getDesc['blabla2'],0,'R',false,0,62,$disY+2,true),
         $pdf->MultiCell(20,"",$getDesc['blabla3'],0,'R',false,0,77,$disY+2,true),
         $pdf->MultiCell(15,"",$getDesc['blabla4'],0,'R',false,0,97,$disY+2,true),
         $pdf->MultiCell(25,"",$getDesc['blabla5'],0,'R',false,0,112,$disY+2,true),
         $pdf->MultiCell(15,"",$getDesc['blabla6'],0,'R',false,0,137,$disY+2,true),
         $pdf->MultiCell(20,"",$getDesc['blabla7'],0,'R',false,0,152,$disY+2,true),
         $pdf->MultiCell(25,"",$getDesc['blabla8'],0,'R',false,0,172,$disY+2,true),   
         $pdf->SetFont('freesans','B',8),
         $pdf->MultiCell(180,"",$getDesc['blabla9'],0,'L',false,0,12,$disY+11,true)
      );

      return $subheader;
   }

   others functions...
}
```

In another `class` call only a `function`

```
$pdf = new TCPDF (PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();

lot of code $pdf->...

$invoice = new invoice();

if(cond == 1){
   $disY = 100;
   $invoice->getSubheader($disY);
} else {
   $disY = 200;
   $invoice->getSubheader($disY);
}

lot of code $pdf->...
```

This `function` must return variables $pdf->SetLineWidt... etc.
But if I use this solution - error

```
Call to a member function SetLineWidth() on null
```

Any advice for a newbie?

Comment: Hi Lubos, The $pdf object does not exist within your second class. This is causing your error.

Comment: oh, I see. Im totally stupid. function getSubheader($pdf,$getDesc,$disY){... thx